# Replace lower case with lower case and upper case with upper case changing suffix of those strings

Tags: sed

can we use sed command to replace lower case with lower case and upper case with upper case changing suffix with those strings in single command ?.

e.g I want to replace `remote2p1898` with `rempte2p1980` and `REMOTE2P1898` with `REMOTE2P1980` in a single file.

currently I am execcuting 2 commands to get such kind of things done.

```
sed -i 's/remote2p1898/remote2p1980/g' <filename>
```

and

```
sed -i 's/REMOTE2P1898/REMOTE2P1980/g' <filename>
```

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(remote2p)1898/\11980/ig' file
```

Combine using a backreference and the `i`(case insensitive) flag on the substitution command.

Comment: That's a very good one! Way better than mine `sed -e command1 -e command2`. Deleting that and +1